# Ajax.ActionLink where to place pushState

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, html, view-helpers

I would like to know when I should be placing the ["pushState" html5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) when using Ajax.ActionLink.

I do not know if I should change it on the OnBegin or OnComplete events within the AjaxOptions or when clicking the link (this last is the one I have seen recomended)...

I know that there are answers regarding this issue, but i have not find any that had clarified me what the difference between the two is.

Thanks¡

Comment: I did it on complete. Cause there isn't any need to do it earlier

Comment: Thank you, that it is what I have finally done¡¡